# how to open ms word document file in browser(inline content-disposition) in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inline, filestreamresult

Im try to open files (inline mode) in browser. It's working fine for notepad and PDF files, but not for MS Office files(MS Word, MS Excel). For Ms office files I always get download screen in browser. Im using following code:

```
public FileStreamResult OpenDoc(string fileName, string contentType){
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
    return File(fileStreams, contentType);
}
```

Can you help?

Comment: This depends on the browser configuration and Office / plugin installation. There is no code that spawns a Word instance in your browser, you need to configure the client PC to do that.

Comment: What configuration you suggest in client PC?

Comment: Using [Chrome Office Viewer](http://chrome.blogspot.nl/2013/04/a-speedy-more-secure-way-to-view.html) for example.

Comment: No, I need to open inline inside browser without any configuration changes

Comment: I thought Office applications stopped loading themselves in browsers a few versions ago.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. Im able to do it in a different way. Im getting file data in byte streams form and setting content type ="text/html" with content-dispostion="inline, filename="+filename 
So what Im doing Im passing bytes to browser without any specific application formats.